# How do I calculate confidence interval with only sample size and confidence level

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval

I'm writing a program that lets users run simulates on a subset of data, and as part of this process, the program allows a user to specify what sample size they want based on confidence level and confidence interval. Assuming a p value of .5 to maximum sample size, and given that I know the population size, I can calculate the sample size. For example, if I have:

Population = 54213

Confidence Level = .95

Confidence Interval = 8

I get Sample Size 150. I use the formula outlined here:

https://www.surveysystem.com/sample-size-formula.htm

What I have been asked to do is reverse the process, so that confidence interval is calculated using a given sample size and confidence level (and I know the population). I'm having a horrible time trying to reverse this equation and was wondering if there is a formula. More importantly, does this seem like an intelligent thing to do? Because this seems like a weird request to me.

Comment: I don't recognize that formula, is your data binomially distributed? Also, usually you would calculate a CI given a sample, so your way of doing it is more "backwards".

Comment: We're assuming the data will have a normal distribution. The actual data is several attributes of a real world object (cost being a biggie). What we wanted to do is say 'if you want this level of confidence, use a sample of this size', but then someone decided it should be reversible.

Comment: Probably more suitable for stats.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should mention (just to be clear) that the CI is estimated for the mean, not the population. In that case, if we assume the population is normally distributed and that we know the population standard deviation SD, then the CI is estimated as

[image]

From this formula you would also get your formula, where you are estimating n.
If the population SD is not known then you need to replace the z-value with a t-value.